# Can't open gnome-terminal with php

Tags: php

I actually try to laucnh a gnome-term with a php script, seems i have some problems with the users www-data;

my script make only a ls -l command in a directory (is just for a test) and i run it with a php page in my local-web site.

here the gnome-terminal command in my bash script (he run perfectly when i double-click on him) :

**gnome-terminal --working-directory=/opt/cuckoo -x bash -c "ls -l"**

and here is the call on the php-page :

**system("/my/path/to/the/script/script.sh");**

i have some echo in my script and i see them in the php page after i try to run the script with the php.page.

i think www-data don't have the right to do so i give the ownership of the script with the chown command, and at last a try the **sudo visudo** command and make the script execute like the user www-data is root (with **NO PASSWD** arg)

But i can't open the terminal and make a ls at last, i try with exec too, and show the result with $ouput butthe result is the same as well.

At last my question is : Php can really run a terminal or maybe a fool myself^^? Thanks for taking time to rescure me ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP can run everything, but depends who spawns it. Forget just running X apps from a web server - you'll need more than just executing them (permissions, DISPLAY and Xauth settings). Read more about the X clients and architecture.

Probably the right place to ask this is at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), since the problem is not in the coding itself.